# Update column title in databse in SQL Server

Tags: ssms-2012

I'd like to update the title of column in a database that I created in SSMS 2012.

I've seen some examples where records in the table are updated, but not the actual column titles.

The column title had a typo so all I want to do is change 'deparment' to department (with a 't' in the middle).

The database is called department.

I believe I'd need to do something along the lines of

Update department (ie the database I'm updating) then

Set?

Can someone please clarify what the rest of the query should look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try: USE department; EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.yourtablename.deparment', 'department', 'COLUMN';

Comment: Hmmm....I got this error when I tried that? Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 238
Either the parameter (at sign)objname is ambiguous or the claimed (at sign)objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.